# C++ string.substr compiles differently

Tags: x11, c++, g++

I have two pairs of files. The source files are identical copies apart from the path to the identical text files they interrogate.
One pair runs on Linux Cinnamon 18.x the other on Raspbian Stretch. Each pair is compiled on its own platform.

```
std::string sTemp = ImportDS18B20("testy.txt");

if (sTemp.find("YES") != std::string::npos) {
  size_t p = sTemp.find("t= ");

  if (p != std::string::npos) {
    p += 3;
    sFloor = sTemp.substr(p);
    uint uTemp = sFloor.length();
    std::cout << uTemp << "   |" << sFloor << "|   " << std::endl;
  }

  break;
}
```

The code produces `5  |19555|` on Raspbian and `6  |19555\n|` on Cinnamon. (`\n` is of course just to represent a `CR` on this site.)
I assume this is a C++ compiler issue. Is that correct? How do I make the code portable?

Comment: Do you by `CR` mean a carriage return (`\r`)? Are the two files on the two machines identical, or is the Cinnamon file a DOS text file?

Comment: I did mean to replicate the effect of a new line as this is how cout displays it. More accurately I think substr() in Cinnamon is picking up the EOL char since there are no other printable chars in the file (and there is no "\r" or "\n" in the file). Both pairs of files are identical as stated - they are both copies made and saved in the Cinnamon box straight to the SD card holding the Raspbian. Both compiled by g++ c11 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your issue is with the ImportDS18B20() function rather than the code you've posted or the compiler. To verify that the files are identical, check the length and md5sum.

I would strip trailing \r (and \n to make it cross-platform)

```
sFloor = sTemp.substr(p);

while (sTemp.back() == '\r' || sTemp.back() == '\n')
    sTemp.pop_back();

uint uTemp = sFloor.length();
```

Mike

Comment: tks for back() - worked. md5's good. Import DS18B20 identical in same cpp's. So I still don't see what was different but no matter with your solution